# dotnet-dump vs createdump analysis

Tags: .net, .net-core, memory-leaks, heap-memory, memory-dump

I am looking for a utility to generate memory dump for my containerized .net applications running on aws eks

We are planning to use createdump or dotnet-dump utility.

```
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.14.2
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.14"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
```

Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically generate dumps upon crash, you might use the `createdump` with appropriate environment variables set to fit your need. For details please refer to [Collect dumps on crash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dumps#collect-dumps-on-crash).

If you just want to manually generate dumps then either `createdump` or `dotnet-dump` will do.

And since you are running the applications in container, you will need to add the `PTRACE` capability via `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` or `--privileged` when you start the container.

Another utility `ProcDump` allows dump generation by rules (e.g., generate dump when low memory or CPU high) which is similar to the DebugDiag in Windows. However I am not sure if Alpine distro is capable to run it or not, as itis not listed in the [install guide](https://github.com/Sysinternals/ProcDump-for-Linux/blob/master/INSTALL.md).